# How to perform a simple reduceByKey in Apache Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to spark and trying to learn. This is rather a simple problem where I've the following code to reduce repeated keys w.r.t to their values.

The dataframe will have the values like this.

```
 subject      object    

  node1        node5
  node1        node6
  node1        node7
  node2        node5
  node2        node7
```

And I want them to reduce like this.

```
 subject      object    

  node1        [node5,node6,node7]
  node2        [node5,node7]
```

I can achieve this using the `groupByKey` method but I wanted to use `reduceByKey` here for which I was unable to understand what would be the right syntax to perform this.

**Here's my code :**

```
    DataFrame records = Service.sqlCtx().sql("SELECT subject,object FROM Graph");


    JavaPairRDD<String,Iterable<String>> rows = records.select("subject","object").toJavaRDD().mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<Row,String,String>(){

                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, String> call(Row row) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2<String, String>(row.getString(0), row.getString(1));
                }

            // this can be optimized if we use reduceByKey instead of groupByKey
    }).distinct().groupByKey().cache();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In general case this cannot be optimized with `reduceByKey`. The inefficient part is the operation istelf not a particular implementation.
- Furthermore this cannot be implemented directly with `reduceByKey` due to incompatible signature. This could be done with `aggregateByKey` or `combineByKey` but it is still not an optimization.
- Finally, if you use `DataFrames` just use `collect_list`:

  ```
  import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

  records.groupBy("subject").agg(collect_list(col("object")));
  ```

Answer (score -1):

There is a way we can apply reduceByKey to optimize, but we would have to 1 transformation before reduceByKey.

```
val keyValuePairs = sc.parallelize(List(("node1","node5"),("node1","node6"),("node1","node7"),("node2","node5"),("node2","node7")))    //Input

val mappedKV = keyValuePairs.map(x => (x._1,Seq(x._2)))

//Transform each value of the K,V pair to 'Seq' (extra transformation)

val reducedKV = mappedKV.reduceByKey(_++_)
```

Then applying '*++*' with reduceByKey.

Output:

> **scala> reducedKV.collect**
>
> **Array[(String, Seq[String])] = Array((node2,List(node5, node7)), (node1,List(node5, node6, node7)))**